# Livewire Multiple checkboxes with the same wire:model , check one to select all

Tags: laravel-livewire

Result view after check [x ]Car 1: checked both

[ x]Car 1 [x ]Car 2

Code:

Component:
public $plan_requirement2 = [];

View:

```
             <label for="requirement2">                                                        
                        <input type="checkbox" id = "requirement2" value="Red car" wire:model="plan_requirement2"> Car 1                                    
               </label>
                <label for="requirement2">
                          <input type="checkbox" id = "requirement2" value="Blue car" wire:model="plan_requirement2"> Car 2
                 </label>
```

Comment: Both elements have the same IDs. All IDs on a page must be entirely unique. You should also specify an index to your models

Answer (score 0):

```
public $plan_requirement2 = [];
```

checkbox attribute must be array

Comment: I did, same problem!

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
   <label>  
    <input type="checkbox" value="Red car" wire:model.defer="plan_requirement2" wire:key="requirement1"> Car 1                                    
               </label>
                <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" value="Blue car" wire:model.defer="plan_requirement2" wire:key="requirement2"> Car 2
                 </label>
```